# How to launch/open apple pay or wallet application

Tags: iphone, swift, xcode8, ios10, applepay

Is there any possibility to launch/open Apple pay or Wallet application from existing application using deeplinking?

Comment: HII @maren iOS did you get any solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible. You can create a .pkpass file and prompt the user to add it to Wallet. Then Wallet will open but there is no url scheme for just opening the Apple Wallet app.

[More informations about URL Schemes in iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: OK thanQ @maximilian_cs

Comment: is this answer true and still valid?

Answer (score 2):

You can deep link to the wallet using:

```
 if let url = URL(string: "wallet://") {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url)
    }
```